# bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool) crash with UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to display tweets in `UITableView`.

Code :-

```
- (void)requestTimeline:(int)count
{    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json"];

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [parameters setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"screen_name"];
    [parameters setObject:@"20" forKey:@"count"];
    [parameters setObject:@"1" forKey:@"include_entities"];

    TWRequest *request = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:parameters requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData1, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
    {
        if (responseData1 != nil)
        {
            NSError *error = nil;
            self.itemsToDisplay = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData1 options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

            if (self.itemsToDisplay != nil)
            {
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error serializing response data %@ with user info %@.", error, error.userInfo);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error requesting timeline %@ with user info %@.", error, error.userInfo);
        }
    }];
}
```

`self` is `UITableViewController`'s subclass.

Due to block, twitter request will be performed on another thread not on main thread. Thats why it get crashed.

`//TWRequest.h`

```
// Issue the request. This block is not guaranteed to be called on any particular thread.
- (void)performRequestWithHandler:(TWRequestHandler)handler;
```

Crash reort:-

> bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xa8e4f50: Tried to obtain the web lock
>   from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may
>   be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing
>   now...

How resolve this issue ?

Thanks...

Comment: Did you try to perform `reloadData` on the main thread?

Comment: yeah I did but doesn't work...

Comment: no you didnt, as his code was wrong. it will help :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the web view must only ever be used from the main thread. much of UIKit -- the tableView reloadData command is also not thread-safe

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    //all you ever do with UIKit.. in your case the reloadData call
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this, may be it helps:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: wrong code - the perform should be on the tableView, not on self. Also I would use a block.. its way more flexible. *not in this case, but in general!)

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

Also below code works :

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                                [self.tableView reloadData];
                            }];
```

Comment: yip, thats the ObjC variant of using GCD (NSOperation is implemented on top of GCD today... _I_ prefer the C dispatch api but it is a matter of taste :D

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
[self.tableView performSelectorInMainThread:@selector(reloadData)];
```

instead of:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```